# Customize google placepicker colors for android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, android-appcompat

I want to customize google place picker widget for android. Can I styling primary and primary dark colors for devices with API below 21 (using appcompat matherial)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to use material design themes below android 5.0. Check This out [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html)