# How to Customizing Google Place Picker widget in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

How to customizing [Google Place picker widget](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker) where we can remove or hide near by list and place picker icon accourding to design.

i google about this but not get any solution for this

yes we can change color in 21 and above [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321281/customize-google-placepicker-colors-for-android)

My Question is

1. is possible to hide near by list and change place piker icon
2. or is any other way to create Custom Plece Picker.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Refer to the following link ["This really helps"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067210/android-place-picker-closes-immediately-after-launch)

Comment: not helpful, i talking about customizing

Comment: i have the same problem, did you find a proper way to do so?

Comment: no, not working on this anymore, if you find way then please update us